# Confirm box inside other confirm

Tags: jquery, asp.net, messagebox, confirm

I have asp button myButton with `OnClientClick` properties which return jquery `myConfirm()` function.

I have function like this:

```
function myConfirm(){
    if(confirm("accept")==true){
        confirm("second message");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        otherFunc();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have a problem, because the second confirm box does not fire. After myButton click jquery fire first confirmation box with OK and Cancel, when I click OK Ii would like to fire second confirm box with second message. How to make two level of box confirmation in jquery?

Comment: what browser you are using? I tried the code is working fine

Comment: Oh sory, it's start work.